# Getting the last month's dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to get the last month's dates from `1st to current date`. Suppose if today's date is `March 25th`, I need to get the dates from `1st to 25th of february`. Suppose if today's date is `March 30th`, I need to get the dates from 1st to `28/29th Feb`, whatever the maximum final date is available. I have searched a lot to get that, but no luck. Can someone please help me how to get this special case done? I am able to do it on another database, but I want to do this on mysql.

Basically what I did for other database is this --> `date between date(to_char(date(add_months(DATE(sysdate) ,-1)),'YYYY-MM-01 00:00:00')) and date(add_months(DATE(sysdate) ,-1))`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to retrieve data that might not be in the database? Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
WHERE d BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01') 
  AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Comment: Jack, thanks for your answer. But how to get just the dates. I am not using this to select columns from particular table. I just want the dates in between that range.

Comment: @rick MySQL isn't very well equipped to generate date ranges; it would be easier to handle gaps in the app layer.

Comment: In the other database I am able to get that exactly what I need. But in Mysql no luck. Coming to the app layer, that is what I was trying in php as we discussed yesterday, but I failed on that side too.

Comment: @rick Use `strtotime('first day of last month')` and see how far that gets you :)

Comment: I did it through programming. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))`. This will automatically limit the result to the last day of the month, so if today's date is March 30th, this will return Feb 28th.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how to get the dates from 1st to till date of last month. i.e., 2014-02-01, 2014-02-02, 2014-02-03 and so on in the result